# Icons not showing as expected (Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022/Windows 10)

Tags: windows, icons, setup-project

**Context**

I have a .NET desktop application that I am updating. I used to make the installer using InnoSetup (years ago) but right now I am trying a Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022 instead.
Everything works fine except the following.

**Problem**

- In Windows 10 > Settings > Apps & features: The application's icon is just a blue square (just solid blue).
- In Programs Menu, the icon turns into a default icon, like for applications that don't have an icon.
- On desktop, default icon (s in Programs Menu).

**More context**
In File Explorer, icons are displayed as expected.
When the application run, icon is fine in taskbar.

The setup project has icons configured for both Programs Menu and desktop and has *AddRemoveProgramsIcon* configured for Settings > Apps & features

The icons are 256x256 .ico files, looking inside with text editor, their content seems to be PNG (which, from Wikipedia, matches Microsoft's recommendations... unless they changed?)

I tried to research this but keywords such a "application icon setup" only lead me to vaguely related results.

Edit: I just found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/iconography/app-icon-construction
but it says that if I have larger icons Windows should accurately scale it down, so providing only 256x256 should be fine I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I also saw this issue and in my case removing compression from the PNG .ico resolved it. I then saw the icon on my program shortcut in the Windows Start folder and on the desktop.